# How can I catch kendo-ui 'dataBound' event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I want to catch `'dataBound'` event in `jQuery`.
Requirement is such as that when `databound` event is fired in `kendo-ui` ,
I have to add some custom logic to `DOM`.

Answer (score 0):

See for example Telerik [API](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound) and [events demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/events).

You need to configure the databound event, then add your logic to the javascript function.

```
<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
    function dataBound(e) {
        var grid = e.sender;
        // Do your custom logic
    }

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            { field: "name" },
            { field: "age" }
        ],
        dataSource: [
            { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
            { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
        ],
        dataBound: "dataBound"
    });
</script>
```